# Public transport journey planner for Lille?

Tags: online-resources, public-transport, france, lille

Normally when I'm looking for a public transport trip planner, I try google maps first. If Google have coverage for the city, it's often a good start, and I can find out the official one later (eg by looking for posters at stations / stops). I have however learnt the hard way that Google doesn't always have up-to-date info, so it's always worth being early...

However, for Lille, Google doesn't seem to have any public transport coverage for the city. So, does anyone know of a public transport journey planner that covers Lille? Ideally something where I put in the addresses at both ends, and it gives me a combination of walking / bus / tram / train / metro directions to get me there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just checked the Transpole website and I think that's exactly what you're looking for.

UPDATE:
New Website - [ilevia](https://www.ilevia.fr/cms/institutionnel/se-deplacer/)

Comment: I believe the website has moved to [here](https://www.ilevia.fr/cms/institutionnel/se-deplacer/).

Comment: @ChristianLescuyer thanks, I updated the answer